# How to retrieve a specific relationship by one of its properties in Cypher? (neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to come up with the Cypher syntax to both:

- Create an index on a relationship property
- Query that index in order to retrieve an specific relationship from one of its values.

Since labels cannot be used for relationships, how could it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't add index to relationships in Neo4j. So, you ca't query database for specific relationship by it's property value.

There are alternatives.

### Data model

You can reorganize data in such way that:

- Specific properties are in nodes
- Create specific relationship types

Usually you can design that in a way when properties that are needed for queries are in nodes, and only additional properties (i.e. `cost`) are in relationship.

Anyway you can query relationship by specific property:

```
MATCH (start)-[:RELATIONSHIP {property: "value"}]->(end)
```

This will end up in fullscan of `:RELATIONSHIP` scope.

#### If you know start/end node id's

If you know id's for start and end nodes, and want to update property for specific relationship, then this one should work:

```
MATCH (start)-[r:RELTYPE {property: "value"}]->(end)
WHERE id(start) = 1 AND id(end) = 2
WITH r
SET r.property = "new_value"
RETURN r
```

### Legacy index

**Warning:** this functionality is **deprecated**. I believe that it will be removed in Neo4j 3.0.0.

But there is - [Relationship indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-relationships.html). You can checkout what it provides and if this functionality can be used in your app.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to do this is just because I need to update the value of a relationship property. This update should not be carried out immediately after a traversal so what would be the fastest way of doing this in Cypher? (I know the IDs of the two nodes involved but there might be more than one relationship of the same type between them...)

Comment: thanks, just what about the performance of this stament? does it also have to perform a fullscan in order to execute the query?

Comment: Nope. It will lookup 2 nodes by their id. Then get list of relationships between them (almost O(1) operation).

Comment: You can always `PROFILE` your query, to see what is happening.